# Where to link background-images when using Sass and Grunt?

Tags: html, css, sass, gruntjs

This is the first project that I am working on where the html and css files are located in separate directories, but this is also the first time that I am using grunt for task automation such as minifying and pre-processing my CSS.

My question is, when I am linking image files to be the background-images for my css...do I link the `url()` in reference to where the scss file lives, or where the processed css file is *going to be*. Or is it just wherever it is if I am in the root directory?

If you look at my css, I am trying to make a background image for my header and it is not finding the file. What am I missing?

Here is a screenshot of my directory in my text editor:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrTNx.jpg

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/build/main.css">
<title>Summer Breeze</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class = "hero">
<h1>Text</h1>
</header>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/build/app.min.js" type="javascript"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.hero {
  background-image: url("../img/house_front.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  height:1500px;
}
```

Just for thoroughness, here's my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      build: {
          src: 'js/app.js',
          dest: 'js/build/app.min.js'
      }
    },
    sass: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
            'CSS/build/main.css': 'CSS/main.scss'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
    scripts: {
        files: ['js/*.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        },
      },
    css: {
      files: ['css/*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass'],
      options: {
          spawn: false,
      }
    }
  }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify','sass','watch']);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You link it from "*processed css file is going to be*" for sure. Given your CSS looks like it is in a sub-folder "build" you need to alter your path (in the SASS, which will compile exactly the same, but to the CSS/build directory) to...

`background-image: url("../../img/house_front.jpg");`

Comment: Thanks much! This worked! If I may ask though, how would `url("../img/house_front.jpg");` not work when the `../` should be going up two directories from where the css file is stored. why would i need to do `../../` ?

Comment: @newman IUt sounds like you might be a bit confused about what `../` does. IT only traverses one directory (I never really thought about it being two dots haha. so `../../` traverses two (etc). Think off it as "up out of build" (puts you in CSS) then "up out of CSS" (puts you in root) then back down into "img" and finally to the file.

Comment: @newman There's nothing wrong with how you are doing it, but personally I keep the SASS in a subfolder like assets/sass/ and then compile it directly to /css it just seems more logical to me that way, and means I DO only ever need `../` to get to /img or anything else. I think your build folder is superflous. You could even keep the SASS and CSS in the same folder of course.